# block firefox local network access (CORS?)

Tags: firefox, security, browser, cors

I could be off on this one, so please forgive me if so...

According to this article:
https://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2022/01/new-chrome-security-measure-aims-to-curtail-an-entire-class-of-web-attack/

Web browsers have the ability to allow remote web servers access to local network resources... ie localhost on the browsing computer, and potentially other network devices behind the browser.  It's enabled by default and there's no UI interface to disable it.

This was news to me and is a bit terrifying.  Why in the world would anyone ever allow a remote site to bounce commands through their browser to other devices internally... presumably protected by a network firewall to prevent exactly that?!?!?!

Can someone explain this to me?  When I google "disable CORS", it appears as though that would make it more open and less secure.  I want to disable the capability outright.

I found one mention of a possible answer at:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS/Errors/CORSDisabled
that references "content.cors.disable", but I can't find a mention of that setting anywhere else, and the link doesn't expand on exactly what it does.  The name sounds like what I want, but I don't want to make that assumption and end up making things worse.

If anyone can shed light on this, it would be appreciated.  If this is the wrong forum, please let me know which SE site I should post it to.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The article you read was written in a sensational manner and is only new
in its degree of sensationalism. In effect, browsers are pretty well
secured against external attack, and local resources are very well
protected.

[Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing)
already exists on all the major browsers, defined as:

> a mechanism that allows restricted resources on a web page to be requested from another domain outside the domain from which the first resource was served.

This means that an innocent-looking advertisement on Amazon cannot
use JavaScript to download code from a malicious third-party site.

You will find more information in the Mozilla article
[Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS)
as to which are the restrictions on accessing third-party websites.

The article you saw talks about Chrome tightening CORS further than
it is today.
If you disable CORS, you will open your browser wide open
to such attacks, which is the opposite of your wish.

If you wish to improve further the protection against malicious
JavaScript, you may use an extension such as NoScript that
disallows the execution of all JavaScript from websites that
have not been white-listed manually by yourself.

Comment: Thank you.  The concerning part was about browsers granting access to devices within the private network of the browser user... ie that the browsers can somehow expose internal networks to external hosts.  I get one website referencing another, but the violation of a network perimeter is what really concerned me.  Can you elaborate on that?

Comment: Absolute rubbish : CORS is only one of your defenses against rogue JavaScript, as there are others. JavaScript executes in a sandbox and cannot get access to any device without your *manual* authorization. Security bugs may exist, but are usually quickly plugged. That article was just cheap sensationalism by someone who understood nothing about the subject.